# New LG G3 randomly crash

Tags: crashes, lg-g3

I have bought a new LG G3 (D855, 16GB Flash, 2GB RAM), and rooted and flashed CM12.1 on it.

The phone works great (somewhat), but sometimes the screen turns itself off and the phone gets stuck in this state. Holding the power button neither turns the phone on nor off, and I have to remove and reinsert the battery to turn it on.

It has happened 7 times since Sunday.

I thought it might be due to overheating (a hunch), but could not find anything to confirm this.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Have you tried a different kernel?

Comment: I have not. What can you recommend?

Comment: I can't recommend anything. it is up to you to find and decide. I've read about this issue somewhere and people reported success by changing the kernel.

Comment: Sounds like the fairly common [LG bootloop issue](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LG_smartphone_bootloop_issues), which Google (and I) attest also happens on the G3.  Some had success with a new battery, or using a heat gun, or tightening screws, or soldering.  I haven't tried all those, but did find that it worked best in cold weather.  Surprised there's no direct question about it here on ASE, as the forums suggest it has hit quite a many.

Answer (score 2):

Had the same issue. Solced by connecting to external power supply. Did some searching and apparently, thus cyclic crashing can be due to a bad battery...