# Cyanogenmod LG G3 crashes and does not boot

Tags: cyanogenmod, 5.1-lollipop, crashes

I have recently rooted my LG G3 D855 and installed the latest stable Cyanogenmod release (Android 5.1.1 Cyanogenmod 12.1-20151117-SNAPSHOT-YOG7DAO1K8-d855).

Every few days it happens that the system crashes. So far it has only happened when I was not using my device (e.g. phone in my pocket). When I press the power button to turn on the screen nothing happens, even after several attempts and waiting between attempts. I believe that the phone is actually off during this phase as no phone calls go through.

Trying to press the power button for longer, hoping that the device will boot, proves to be unsuccessful as well. Trying the recovery buttons combination is inconclusive as well. When these issues occurred the battery was always almost full.

Luckily enough on this phone it's possible to remove the battery, and this is only thing that works. Once it boots up everything seems to be working fine. But obviously this is a really annoying issue and it's making my phone be unreliable.

Everything was working fine prior to installing the custom cyanogenmod ROM.

Is there anyway to find out what's causing the issue? And of course, are there any fixes for this?

Comment: @jis Your answer is not constructive. Why are you asking me a question if you already have the answer in my post? Also, in my post I stated that I am using a stable version of Cyanogenmod, and not an unstable one. Finally, you are suggesting something which is completely unrelated to my question.

Comment: It was a rhetorical question :)
I thought it well, why make more problems by installing CM when stock was ok... I have very bad personal experience with CM stability on my Samsung Galaxy phone and Nexus tablet, so I will never enter this bandwagon again.
Here are some useful posts for you:
http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/132218/new-lg-g3-randomly-crash
https://www.reddit.com/r/LGG3/comments/34xjyl/lg_g3_keeps_randomly_restarting/
http://forum.cyanogenmod.org/topic/118772-phone-crashes-and-another-bug/

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend a hard reset in recovery. If you cannot boot into recovery, try using a computer to re-flash the system.